# how internal anchors in XSL work?

Tags: xslt, anchor

i've 2 frames which both render different html pages using XSLT. Means, the container html file has 2 frames whose source are 2 different XML files.

Left frame displays menus and right frame displays content. content on right frame has different sections.

i want to achieve the following:

if i click on a hyperlink on left frame, it should take me to the section on right frame.
I can easily do that with HTML using anchors but i don't know how it can be done using XSL.

my menu linka are coming from an xml which will be static. but my xml on right side will change every time depending on the link that was clicked on last page.

let me explain: i've a page where on right frame, i've few links, say a, b ,c ,d. When i click on a, it will take me to next page (which is also divided into 2 frames : content for left frame are menu items coming from an xml, content for right frame will come from a.xml if a was clicked and b.xml if b was clicked.

now, when while forming the for a on first page, i've to specify the location of my container html holding 2 frames on the next page and i've to pass 'a' as a parameter in so that right frame on next page can call a.xml. I set the location of right frame in the container html on .

Now, i want that my menu hyperlinks on left frame should take me to the desired section on right frame. I also need a way to read the parameter passed in url in my xsl for left frame so that it can take me to correct xml for right page.

Comment: Did you ask the same question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324535/how-anchors-work-in-xsl?

Comment: @magic: Please delete your other, duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT produces HTML. You know how to do it with HTML. Where is the problem?

Comment: plz provide a solution to my problem. i've explained  it little more.

Comment: @magic: Nobody can help you with programming questions if you don't show any of your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those questions that are best answered by just giving it try and seeing what happens.  I can't see why it shouldn't work ultimately the result of the XSLT is HTML.

Comment: plz provide a solution to my problem. i've explained  it little more.