# how anchors work in xsl?

Tags: xslt, anchor

my menu links are coming from an xml which will be static. but my xml on right side will change every time depending on the link that was clicked on last page.

let me explain:
i've a page where on right frame, i've few links, say a, b ,c ,d.
When i click on a, it will take me to next page (which is also divided into 2 frames : content for left frame are menu items coming from an xml, content for right frame will come from a.xml if a was clicked and b.xml if b was clicked.

now, when while forming the  for a on first page, i've to specify the location of my container html holding 2 frames on the next page and i've to pass 'a' as a parameter in  so that right frame on next page can call a.xml. I set the location of right frame in the container html on .

Now, i want that my menu hyperlinks on left frame should take me to the desired section on right frame. I also need a way to read the parameter passed in url in my xsl for left frame so that it can take me to correct xml for right page.

Comment: Did you ask the same question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324410/how-internal-anchors-in-xsl-work

Answer (score 0):

Xsl has no support for hyperlinks and does not understand URL's.

What platform are you using? How are you transforming your Xsl to html? Can you update your question and post some code so we can better understand what you are trying to achieve?